# Adding Images to Quiz App

Tags: image, swift

First I would like to apologize for my ignorance, as I am just starting to learn how to code.  I am working on a basic quiz app.  My question is how would I add images to each question on a case by case basis?  What I want is a different image to show up for each question.

Here is my code thus far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var QuestionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var Button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var Button3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var Button4: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var LabelEnd: UILabel!
    var CorrectAnswer = String()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from     a nib.
        Hide()

        RandomQuestions()   
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func RandomQuestions(){
    var RandomNumber = arc4random() % 4
    RandomNumber += 1

        switch (RandomNumber){

        case 1:
            QuestionLabel.text = "Guess the Athlete"
            Button1.setTitle("Kobe Bryant", forState:   UIControlState.Normal)
            Button2.setTitle("Lebron James", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button3.setTitle("Magic Johnson", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button4.setTitle("Shaq", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "1"

        case 2:
            QuestionLabel.text = "Guess the Athlete"
            Button1.setTitle("Paul Gasol", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button2.setTitle("Allen Iverson", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button3.setTitle("Tim Duncan", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button4.setTitle("Jeremy Lin", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "1"
            break

        case 3:
            QuestionLabel.text = "Guess the Athlete"
            Button1.setTitle("Blake Griffin", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button2.setTitle("Chris Paul", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button3.setTitle("Shaq", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button4.setTitle("Tony Parker", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "2"
            break

        case 4:
            QuestionLabel.text = "Guess the Athlete"
            Button1.setTitle("Dirk Nowitzki", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button2.setTitle("JJ Redick", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button3.setTitle("Ray Allen", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button4.setTitle("Chris Anderson", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "4"
            break

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    var timer = NSTimer()

    func Hide() {
        LabelEnd.hidden = true
        timer.invalidate()  //You can remove timer here.
    }

    func UnHide(){
        LabelEnd.hidden = false
    }

    @IBAction func Button1Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        UnHide()
        if(CorrectAnswer == "1"){
            LabelEnd.text = "Correct!"
            LabelEnd.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Hide"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
         RandomQuestions()

        }
        else{
            LabelEnd.text = "Wrong"
            LabelEnd.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Hide"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func Button2Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        UnHide()
        if(CorrectAnswer == "2"){
            LabelEnd.text = "Correct!"
            LabelEnd.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Hide"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            RandomQuestions()

        }
        else{
            LabelEnd.text = "Wrong"
            LabelEnd.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Hide"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }    

    @IBAction func Button3Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        UnHide()
        if(CorrectAnswer == "3"){
            LabelEnd.text = "Correct!"
            LabelEnd.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Hide"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            RandomQuestions()

        }
        else{
            LabelEnd.text = "Wrong"
            LabelEnd.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Hide"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func Button4Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        UnHide()
        if(CorrectAnswer == "4"){
            LabelEnd.text = "Correct!"
            LabelEnd.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Hide"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            RandomQuestions()

        }
        else{
            LabelEnd.text = "Wrong"
            LabelEnd.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Hide"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The classes you're looking for are `UIImage` and `UIImageView`. You can add a `UIImageView` instance to your Interface Builder `xib` file, just like the buttons and the label. Then, you can add another  `@IBOutlet` property for it, like:

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
```

Next, you'll need to add image files. Let's assume you have one named "`Kobe.png`". Drag it into your Xcode project, either alongside your source files, or by creating a new image asset in the `Images.xcassets` file that you probably have in your project. The assets approach is more modern, but it's slightly more involved, and dragging it into your project works fine for a beginner.

Once you have the file in your project, you can access it as an image object like so:

```
UIImage(named: "Kobe")
```

Then, to put this all together, you can assign it to the `image` property of an image view:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Kobe")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  So i got the image to show but ran into another issue:

Is there a way the class UIImage can automatically resize the image to fit neatly on the screen?  Right now the pictures are large and are covering the buttons.

Comment: You can add a width/height constraint to the image view in Interface Builder. Set it to "less than or equal".

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a `UIImageView` outlet to display images

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Swift... But after creating a new `UIImageView`
you can use this code to determine how a view lays out its content when its bounds change. Which might work for you, otherwise you might have to resize the images?

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

Other examples would be:

```
imageView.contentMode= UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
```

Comment: hmm...some of the bigger photos are still covering the buttoms.. and when I change the simulator from iPhone 6 to 6+ it seems to go outta whack.